# VB.Net Timer makes other Forms lag

Tags: timer, cpu, backgroundworker

I have the issue that using one or two timers on form1 and at the same time showing form2 makes form2 lag everytime the timer refreshs with its interval. If I try to move the Form2 while Form1 is running with its timers it stocks every 500ms and its annoying and makes the program feel slow.

I know I could just use a Backgroundworker but I want to use as less CPU as possible, using a Backgroundworker my Program increases CPU up to 10% (I don't know why, probably because of using a second thread? Is it possible to reduce the CPU Usage?)

Or is there something else, some code I could add to make the Form2 responsible while the Form1 timer is refreshing without Threading or atleast without a Backgroundworker?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Well at the end Im using a threading.timer. :)